# Create form on plugin options page that creates submenu pages for that plugin

Tags: forms, admin-menu

I've created a plugin that adds an admin menu section that is visible to clients (Client Section) when they login and another that is only available to our staff (Staff Section).

Our staff needs to be able to add content to both sections without doing any programming or messing with files.

Is there a way to create a form on my admin options page that creates subpages in the admin menu of the two sections I've created?

So far I've created the form but I'm stumped on how to make it do what I need it to do.

[image: screenshot of form]

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <div class="page-title asl-contain">
    <div class="label"><label for="asl_page_title">Page Title</label></div>
      <div class="page-title-input"><input type="text" name="asl_page_title" id="asl_page_title" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wysiwyg asl-contain"><?php wp_editor( '' , 'asl_texteditor_id', $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'asl_wysiwyg_content') ); ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="asl-contain">
      <div class="label"><label for="asl_menu">Page Location</label></div>
        <div class="checkboxes">
          <select name="asl-menu">
            <option value="hidden-page">Staff Section (hidden from client)</option>
            <option value="regular-page">Client Section (visible to client)</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="asl-button"><input type="submit" name="submit"></div>
    </form>
```